# Show that for every $x \in G$ the subset $H \cup (xH)$ is also a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

one of the questions for the midterm.

I am not sure how to prove both. Please, any tip or suggestions would be great!

Comment: for question 1, what do you think you have to check to make sure it is a subgroup???

Comment: if it has order 2?

Comment: what has order 2??? $H\cup xH$??? No... first of all, take an element in $xH$ and check if its inverse is in $H\cup xH$

Comment: how do you show that if its inverse in that?

Comment: $(xh)^{-1}=xh$ as every element has order $2$... do you se why???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes I do. I got the the proof for the subgroup. How do you show that if G is finite then G=2^n for some integer n??

Comment: ok, what is the order of $H\cup xH$ for $x\notin H$??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10880/discussion-between-dafty-and-praphulla-koushik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: first, show that $G$ is abelian, by using the fact that $(ab)^2=1$.

Once you have shown this, it will be straightforward to verify the group axioms one by one.

Comment: which group axioms? all of them?

Comment: @Dafty There aren't that many to check! The identity is already in $H$, so you just have to prove that $H \cup xH$ is closed under inverses and under products.

Comment: hey how do you show that G is abelian

Comment: @Dafty $(ab)^2 = 1 \Rightarrow (ab) = (ab)^{-1}$. Do you know a formula for $(ab)^{-1}$?

Comment: no I am not sure about the formula. I missed a few classes due to job related stuff so I couldnt attend classes...

Comment: @Dafty $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$. I suggest you try proving it yourself!

Comment: Hey marie I got (a).
how do you show if G is finite, then absolute(G) is finite for n integers?